# ExactTarget - how to prevent a SSJS Send(); function from being executed when Landing Page loaded?

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud

I currently have the following Landing Page code in place which is to be placed in a Script Activity and run on schedule every day.

```
var uis = "z_Testing"

var esd = Send.Definition.Init(uis);

var status = esd.Send();
```

The challenge is that if this Landing Page URL is opened within the ExactTarget interface, the User Initiated Send within the code is fired off [esd.Send();].  This could lead to a future user examining my code, clicking on the URL within the interface and accidentally firing off the User Initiated Send to the audience unintentionally.  Any ideas on how this could be prevented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has often frustrated me, but I think you can over come this with the `_MessageContext` [personalization string](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/#section_2).

Probably the easiest way would be to create a variable based on an `if` statement.

Try the following near the top of the page -

```
%%[ 
   SET @runscript = false

   IF _messagecontext == "LANDINGPAGE" OR _messagecontext == "SITE" THEN
       SET @runscript = true
   ENDIF
]%%
```

Then in your SSJS block use this code:

```
set runscript = Variable.GetValue("@runscript");

if (runscript) {
    var status = esd.Send();
};
```

You may also just not run any of the SSJS and put all of it in a conditional - I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good solution!  I've finally resorted to using a script activity using an HTTP.GET([insert landing page URL here]) with the inclusion of a "token" parameter.  The Landing Page then accepts this and only runs the rest of the code if the token is correct.  My token at the moment is consisted of a set string concatenated with todays date.